# How to prevent LD_PRELOAD or ld.so.preload configuration?

Tags: libc, preloading

Due to license problem, few libraries cannot be linked statically.

So is it possible to prevent/detect preloaded library, either through LD_PRELOAD environment variable or through /etc/ld.so.preload configuration?

The previous can be detected through getenv(). But I have no idea about the other method.

I think there might be a general way to do it, is it?

Answer (score 12):

> is it possible to prevent/detect preloaded library, either through LD_PRELOAD environment variable or through /etc/ld.so.preload configuration?

You appear to be trying to implement some kind of anti-hacking protection. If so, it would be worth your while to study existing crackproofing techniques. [This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1886411794) describes a few.

Note that there are *many* other techniques to inject "foreign" code into your application, besides `LD_PRELOAD` and `/etc/ld.so.preload`. A couple that immediately come to mind are: `LD_AUDIT`, running under debugger, and renaming/replacing `libc.so`.

You have very little hope of stopping a moderately-sophisticated attacker. On Linux, I can build my own `libc.so.6`, and I can rename `LD_PRELOAD` to something else. I can also build my own kernel, and have it automatically inject `myhack.so` into your process without any user-space visible effects. Or I can simply make system calls do something else when executed by your application.

> ... the LD_PRELOAD ... can be detected through `getenv()`

That would stop only the least sophisticated attacker, for two reasons:

- the preloaded library could itself interpose `getenv()`, and can hide `LD_PRELOAD` from your application, and
- the `LD_PRELOAD` only matters at process startup. After the process has started, the preloaded library can easily remove `LD_PRELOAD` from the environment before your application has any chance to examine it.